# How do I create a read-only ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

Initial rendering is very slow in `ng-repeat`. How do I create a read-only version of `ng-repeat`, such that when the array that you're iterating over changes, the rendered HTML does not change

Comment: What do you mean by readonly? `ng-repeat` tells angular to repeat the html for each item in the array, if you have nothing binding inputs to `ng-model` then it is read only as the user cannot change any values.

Comment: If you push something extra into $scope.items, the html will re-render - correct? This method stops it rerendering.

Comment: Yes that is correct, but you could also just bind to an array that will never change because you have no code that will change it. I didn't understand what you meant by read-only, it's a bit clearer now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A double colon makes things in Angular read-only. Use the following syntax:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in ::items">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Mind you this is a feature implemented in Angular 1.3 which is still in beta.

Comment: What does this do? Is it keeping the items from participating in the digest?

Answer (score 0):

if read only, have you tried bindonce? 
 https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce